# is it possible to use Event Sourcing with StAX XML event sequences

Tags: java, xml, event-sourcing, stax

I've got an XML performance problem that I'm looking to solve.

Specifically I've got the same small/medium sized XML file that's being parsed many hundreds of times.

The functionality is bound to a StAX XML event reader. Its output cannot be cloned or otherwise copied, the only way to reproduce the needed functionality is to run this XML event reader over the XML document again.

For performance I would like to read the XML into a StAX event sequence eagerly, and then replay that event sequence rather than re-parse the XML each time.

I believe the problem is implementation: while this idea is reasonable in principal, "Events" are expressed as state-changes against the XMLStreamReader which has a large API surface, a large portion (but not all) of which is related to its "current" event.

Does a system like this already exist?

If I have to build it myself, what might be the best way to ensure correctness?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to represent an XML document in memory, to avoid parsing it repeatedly, is to use one of the many tree models (JDOM2 and XOM are the best in my view, though many people still use the horrible old DOM model simply because it's packaged in the JDK). So I guess I'm asking why doesn't this "obvious" approach work for you?

There are cases where (internally within Saxon) I use a replayable stream of events instead, simply because storing the events and then replaying them is a bit more efficient than building a tree and then walking the tree. I don't use StaX events for this, I use my own class `net.sf.saxon.event.EventBuffer` which holds a list of `net.sf.saxon.event.Event` objects. Perhaps this event model is a bit better designed for the purpose, being rather simpler than the StAX model. Saxon doesn't have any logic to read an `EventBuffer` as a StAX event stream, but it would be easy enough to add. It's open source code, so see if you can adapt it.